# read from XML in java

Tags: java, javascript, xml, getelementbyid

I'm trying to read from xml by this code and its not working .. I need to read from id in the specific tag (getelementbyid)
what I need to change in my java code

THIS is my xml code

```
<book>
<person>
<name>
  <first id=1 name="Kiran"/>
  <first id=2 name="Pai"/>
  </name>
    <age>22</age>

</person>
<person>
<name>
  <first id=1 name="Bill"/>
  <first id=2 name="Gates"/>
    </name>
  <age>46</age>
</person>
<person>
<name>

  <first id=1 name="Steve"/>
  <first id=2 name="Jobs"/>
    </name>
  <age>40</age>
</person>
</book>
```

and this is my java code

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class XMLReader {

 public static void main(String argv[]) {

  try {
  File file = new File("c:\\MyXMLFile.xml");
  DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
  DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
  Document doc = db.parse(file);
  doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
  System.out.println("Root element " + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
  NodeList nodeLst = doc.getElementsByTagName("employee");
  System.out.println("Information of all employees");

  for (int s = 0; s < nodeLst.getLength(); s++) {

    Node fstNode = nodeLst.item(s);

    if (fstNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

           Element fstElmnt = (Element) fstNode;
      NodeList fstNmElmntLst = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("firstname");
      Element fstNmElmnt = (Element) fstNmElmntLst.item(0);
      NodeList fstNm = fstNmElmnt.getChildNodes();
      System.out.println("First Name : "  + ((Node) fstNm.item(0)).getNodeValue());
      NodeList lstNmElmntLst = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("lastname");
      Element lstNmElmnt = (Element) lstNmElmntLst.item(0);
      NodeList lstNm = lstNmElmnt.getChildNodes();
      System.out.println("Last Name : " + ((Node) lstNm.item(0)).getNodeValue());
    }

  }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Is it even valid XML to have your id attributes not surrounded by quotes? Also, you have this code `fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("firstname");` which is looking for elements like `<firstname>` of which you have none.

Comment: @thatidiotguy No, it isn't and using the same id ("Identifier") for multiple elements isn't too good, either.

Comment: like @thatidiotguy said, add quotes for  your id attributes and if some exception is coming, add that info as well to your question :)

Comment: @Alexander, it not ideal to have same attributes values with out namespaces but if the XML is valid, at least it should return the first occurence, isn't it ?

Comment: This XML doesn't validate. As to whether or not you can have the same IDs, I'm pretty sure it'll validate as an XML document, but in this case, none of these fields should have IDs except for Person.

Comment: @Arkantos sure it would, but its missleading. IDs should be unique. If they're not unique, don't call em ID^^

Comment: @Alexander... ya I understand that. I'm just asserting that at least some part of it should work even if it's not as expected ;)

Comment: I know it is wrong from my xml ..but is just an example let you know my problem ..my Q is I needto know how can I read by get element by ID

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at JAXB. It is part of Java SE. You only need to map your XML schema to few POJO classes and describe them with JAXB annotations.

Possible code to map an XML to an object, and vice versa, will take ~5 lines.

You can read about it here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
public class XMLReader {
public static void main(String argv[]) {

  try {
    File file = new File("c:\\MyXMLFile.xml");
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = db.parse(file);
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    System.out.println("Root element " +  doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
   NodeList nodeLst = doc.getElementsByTagName("name");
   System.out.println("Information of all employees");

   for (int s = 0; s < nodeLst.getLength(); s++) {

   Node fstNode = nodeLst.item(s);

   if (fstNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

   Element fstElmnt = (Element) fstNode;
   NodeList fstNmElmntLst = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("first");

   Element fstNmElmnt = (Element) fstNmElmntLst.item(0);

   System.out.println("First Name : "  +fstNmElmnt.getAttributeNode("name").getNodeValue());


  Element lstNmElmnt = (Element) fstNmElmntLst.item(1);
  System.out.println("Last Name : "  +lstNmElmnt.getAttributeNode("name").getNodeValue());

}

  }
 } catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

And correct your xml to quote the attributes:

```
<book>
<person>
<name>
  <first id="1" name="Kiran"/>
  <first id="2" name="Pai"/>
  </name>
    <age>22</age>

</person>
<person>
<name>
  <first id="1" name="Bill"/>
  <first id="2" name="Gates"/>
    </name>
  <age>46</age>
</person>
<person>
<name>

  <first id="1" name="Steve"/>
  <first id="2" name="Jobs"/>
    </name>
  <age>40</age>
</person>
</book>
```

Answer (score -1):

One of the problems is that the built in Java XML libraries are only so-so. While meant primarily for for HTML, if you are not using xpaths,  [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) is a lot easier to work with.

```
String yourXml = ...
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(yourXml, "", Parser.xmlParser()); 
    for (Element person : doc.getElementsByTag("person")) {
        String firstName = person.getElementById("1").text();
        String lastName = person.getElementById("2").text();
    }
```